# Box2d-Jquery : Disabling mouse event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, box2d

I am writing a simple game using Box2d-Jquery. By default the position of the DOM elements can be handled by clicking and dragging those corresponding elements. How can this mouse event be disabled so that the movement of the elements is not disturbed by any mouse clicks? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you could comment the method body

```
  updateMouseDrag = function() {
    /*var body, md;
    if (isMouseDown && (!mouseJoint)) {
      body = getBodyAtMouse();
      if (body) {
        md = new b2MouseJointDef();
        md.bodyA = world.GetGroundBody();
        md.bodyB = body;
        md.target.Set(mouseX, mouseY);
        md.collideConnected = true;
        md.maxForce = 300.0 * body.GetMass();
        mouseJoint = world.CreateJoint(md);
        body.SetAwake(true);
      }
    }
    if (mouseJoint) {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        return mouseJoint.SetTarget(new b2Vec2(mouseX, mouseY));
      } else {
        world.DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
        return mouseJoint = null;
      }
    }*/
  };
```

this method will create mouse joint which is supported by box2d to handle mouse event on the bodies in the world.

Or just comment the invoke to updateMouseDrag() in method update(). update() is the game loop method.

Comment: Thanks a ton..Worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an old question, but I figured it out this evening:

Box2D Jquery doesn't set any DOM accessible User Data, so we have to set some.

In your $('element').box2d, set an option 'mouseEnabled' to true/false.

Then, in

```
$.fn.extend({
box2d: function(options) {
```

add the options:

```
mouseEnabled = opts['mouseEnabled'];
userData = {
    mouseEnabled:mouseEnabled,
    //Add additional options here
  }
```

Below that, find the line that says

```
createDOMObjects(absolute_elements, shape, static_, density, restitution, friction);
```

and append userData to the arguments so that it says:

```
createDOMObjects(absolute_elements, shape, static_, density, restitution, friction, userData);
```

NEXT

Find createDOMObjects and append userData to the arguments

```
  createDOMObjects = function(jquery_selector, shape, static_, density, restitution, friction, userData) {
```

You are now going to need to add userData to the b2BodyDefinitions of each body.
So append userData to createBox and createCircle.
Apply the userData to the BodyDef like so within the two creation functions:
        bodyDef.userData = userData;

If you did it right, if you logged out the body on getBodyAtMouse(); you would see m_userData is no longer null!

LASTLY
In updateMouseDrag, add a return is the userData for mouseEnabled is false!

```
if (body) {
    console.log(body.m_userData)
    if(body.m_userData.mouseEnabled == false){return;}
    md = new b2MouseJointDef();
    md.bodyA = world.GetGroundBody();
    md.bodyB = body;
    md.target.Set(mouseX, mouseY);
    md.collideConnected = true;
    md.maxForce = 300.0 * body.GetMass();
    mouseJoint = world.CreateJoint(md);
    body.SetAwake(true);
  }
```

VOILA!
Now, wherever you insantiate your box2D elements, just add mouseEnabled to it!

```
$(".block").box2d({'y-velocity':10, 'mouseEnabled':false});
```

If you want to change the mouseEnable during runTime, just set the body.m_userData.mouseEnabled to anything!